# Why is there a delay in routing when using Zuul + Ribbon with Eureka turned off?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

When `Zuul` routes to microservice it takes around 5 ms but on *30th* second it adds 100ms + delay.

I added `ribbon.eureka.ServerListRefreshInterval=60000`. Now I see it refreshing its list of servers every minute but still on *30th* sec the delay happens.

Can someone please tell me what's happening at *30th* sec?

My Zuul configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: xxxx
  profiles:
    active: default
  cloud:
    config:
      failFast: true
  security:
    enabled: false
  main:
    banner-mode: 'off'
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
zuul:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 60000  # starting the connection
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000   # monitor the continuous incoming data flow
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    auth:
      path: /xxx/xx/**
      stripPrefix: false
      #url: http://localhost:9003/
    xx:
      path: /xx/xx/**
      stripPrefix: false
      #url: http://localhost:9002/
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  ConnectTimeout: 120000
  eureka:
    enabled: false
  security:
    ignored: /**
  basic:
    enabled: false
  management:
    security:
      enabled: false
xx:
 ribbon:
   eureka:
      enabled: false
   ServerListRefreshInterval: 60000
```

Comment: check .. below properties

eureka.client.refresh.interval
eureka.appinfo.replicate.interval
eureka.serviceUrlPollIntervalMs

Comment: I m not using Eureka

Comment: Please show your zuul configuration.

Comment: Updated with my zuul config

Comment: Have you monitored the VM to see if it's doing a GC about that time?

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out.. the issue was not with zuul or Eureka. We had Swagger enabled and all our controllers had those annotations. So after removing Swagger I do not see that slowness .. so not sure what Swagger is doing in the background.